# How to create a Google Drive application available for every file in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, mime

I have created a Google Drive application following the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/enable-sdk.

I want to be able to open any file and folder stored in Google Drive with my Google Drive application by right clicking "Open with"

I tried to set */* as "Default MIME Types", to avoid to have to set the full list... but it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

/ is not a valid MIME type or file extension, you have to explicitly list all MIME types and extension your app can support in the Google Drive SDK tab of the APIs Console for your peoject.

Comment: Sorry, I meant \*/\* as MIME Type